# Rust Cocoa - How to Iterate NSArray

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, rust, iterator, nsarray

From [`brandonhamilton/image-capture-core-rs`](https://github.com/brandonhamilton/image-capture-core-rs)'s `ICCameraDevice.mediaFiles()` I can get the `NSArray::count()` (from [`core-foundation-rs`](https://github.com/servo/core-foundation-rs)) :

```rust
let cam_media_files = camera_device.mediaFiles();

println!(
  NSArray::count(cam_media_files)  // 123
);
```

But how can you iterate this `Object`?

I've tried a couple things:

```rust
// for media_file in NSArray::array(nil, cam_media_files) {
// for media_file in NSArray::arrayWithObject(nil, cam_media_files) {
for media_file in cam_media_files {
    println!("   media_file: {:?}", media_file);
}
```

All result in something like this:

```rust
error[E0277]: `*mut Object` is not an iterator
  --> src/image_capture_core_mod.rs:86:31
   |
86 |             for media_file in cam_media_files {
   |                               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ `*mut Object` is not an iterator
   |
   = help: the trait `Iterator` is not implemented for `*mut Object`
   = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `IntoIterator` for `*mut Object`
   = note: required by `into_iter`
```

Not much to work with here:
https://docs.rs/cocoa/0.24.0/cocoa/foundation/trait.NSArray.html

What am I missing?

Thank you ‍♂️

Comment: What is the objective-c tag for?

Comment: @ElTomato this is Rust calling ObjC, a C-Bridge: https://github.com/brandonhamilton/image-capture-core-rs/blob/master/src/camera_device.rs#L4

Comment: I guess https://docs.rs/cocoa/0.24.0/cocoa/foundation/trait.NSArray.html#method.objectAtIndex, your question is quite unclear and the crate have zéro doc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the docs, `NSArray` has an `objectAtIndex` method, so this should work:

```
for idx in 0..NSArray::count (cam_media_files) {
   let media_file = NSArray::objectAtIndex (cam_media_files, idx);
   // ...
}
```

or if you want to do it with iterators:

```
for media_file in (0..NSArray::count (cam_media_files)).map (|idx| NSArray::objectAtIndex (cam_media_files, idx)) {
   // ...
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You're missing the `.iter()`:

```
for media_file in cam_media_files.iter() {
```

In ObjC, NSArray implements [NSFastEnumeration](https://docs.rs/cocoa-foundation/0.1.0/src/cocoa_foundation/foundation.rs.html#709-711), which is how ObjC implements its `for...in` syntax.

This crate's bridge to NSFastEnumeration provides `iter()`, which returns an [NSFastIterator](https://docs.rs/cocoa-foundation/0.1.0/src/cocoa_foundation/foundation.rs.html#677-707). (NSFastIterator is not a Cocoa type. It's something this crate provides to bridge NSFastEnumeration to Iterator.)

Note that this crate applies NSFastEnumeration to all object types (that's what `id` means), even ones that don't implement NSFastEnumeration in Cocoa. That means that you can iterate on *anything*...but it'll crash at runtime if it's not supported by Cocoa, and you won't get a compile time warning or error:

```
let string = cam_media_files.objectAtIndex(0);
for x in string.iter() {} // *Crash* (NSString doesn't support this)
```

Comment: Hi @Rob Napier, thank you for the answer. Adding `iter()` errors with this:
`^^^^ method not found in *mut Object`. I'll take a look at `NSFastEnumeration` though! 

Comment: I tested this with cocoa 0.24, `use cocoa::base::*` and `use cocoa::foundation::*`. Do you have a small project that we can test with? https://gist.github.com/rust-play/97ba551bd1eb5bb13fc2298c4b2603c5

Comment: `ICCameraDevice.mediaFiles()` returns `[ICCameraItem]?`: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/imagecapturecore/iccameradevice/1507811-mediafiles See https://github.com/brandonhamilton/image-capture-core-rs/blob/master/src/camera_device.rs#L103 I don't know if that still should work with `iter`?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know Cocoa well, and I'm just giving you a path that I hope can help you find the solution.

You use do `let cam_media_files = camera_device.mediaFiles();` and `mediaFiles(self) -> id;`

Wath is id?

```
pub type id = *mut runtime::Object;
```

The doc about runtime::Object this is https://docs.rs/objc/0.2.7/objc/ and you can use msg_send! crate to call Cocoa methode

```
let cls = class!(NSObject);
let obj: *mut Object = msg_send![cls, new];
let hash: usize = msg_send![obj, hash];
```

Comment: While this suggests more things you can do with a `*mut Object`, it doesn't really answer OP's question. Are you proposing sending a message to iterate the array? What message? What would the code and output look like?

Comment: Hello @kmdreko. Yes, is not really answer. Is more a reflection, an idea. But is more clearly presented in answer instead of comment.